# Updated value not being saved to db in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm new to Ruby and Rails, and a piece of code is giving me trouble.
The code is as follows

```
projects_controller.rb

def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  old=@project.department.split(";")
  if @project.update_attributes(params[:project]) 
  else
 render('edit')
end

new=@project.department.split(";")
new.each { |new_each| 
    if (old.include?(new_each) == false)

    @users = User.where(:code => new_each)
    c=@users.first
    c.projects = "#{c.projects};#{@project.id}"
    c.save

end}
#Erroneous area
old.each { |old_each|
if (new.include?(old_each) == false)
    @users = User.where(:code => old_each)
    #c=@users.first
    @users.first.projects.slice!(";#{@project.id}")
    @users.save
end}
#End erroneous area
end
```

It is supposed to update `@users.first.projects` column after removing the outdated project id, but it doesn't. I tried both `slice!` and `slice` and also `gsub`, none of them worked. Am I missing something? Do I need some library to make `slice!` method work?

**EDIT 1**

```
#Erroneous area
old.each { |old_each|
if (new.include?(old_each) == false)
    @users = User.where(:code => old_each)
    c=@users.first
    c.projects.slice!(";#{@project.id}")
    c.save
end}
#End erroneous area
```

is not working as well.

**EDIT 2:**

```
#Erroneous area
old.each { |old_each|
if (new.include?(old_each) == false)
    @users = User.where(:code => old_each)
    c=@users.first
    c.projects.slice!(";#{@project.id}")
            puts c.projects
    c.save
            puts c.projects
end}
#End erroneous area
```

I updated the code to have a couple of puts commands.
These are working fine and I am getting the expected result on the console.

The only problem here is that the `c.projects` is not being saved to the `users` model.

Comment: What are you attempting to do exactly with this line: `@users.first.projects.slice!(";#{@project.id}")`? And shouldn't the following line be `@users.first.save` (or better, uncomment your `c = @users.first` and use `c` on the next two lines)? `save` isn't a method of a collection of ActiveRecords, so I'm not sure why you didn't get an error with this code.

Comment: You don't use CamelCase in your code, why are you using it in the rest of your explanation?  Please edit your text to be human-readable.

Comment: The `slice!` Command Was To Delete A Project Id From A List Of Ids Stored In projects Column Of users Table.
Also @mbratch, It Didn't Work.
...What's CamelCase?

Comment: "What's CamelCase?" :D:D:D:D comment of the week!

Comment: ...I Really Don't Know, And I'd Appreciate It If You Enlightened Me.

Comment: @roippi, actually the post is all in Title Case. Akshay, This Is Title Case. ThisIsCamelCase. This is normal capitalization of a sentence in English (only proper names and first word in a sentence is capitalized).

Comment: If you do `.slice(";#{@project.id}")` it will give you just ";#{@project.id}" if it finds it in `projects`, or it will give `nil` if it can't. In other words, it deletes everything except what you specified. Is that what you intended?

Comment: But isn't the rest of the string now stored in `projects` ? Cause that's the part I need.
What I thought it meant was that it'll delete that section in the string, and return the deleted value in that statement, but keep the rest of the string in `c.projects`. Will it not do that?

Comment: And yeah, I've always had a habit of typing in title case.